# Would this be a possible work around for the issue of the HTML 5 SoundCloud Widget not autoplaying for iOS?

Tags: ios, api, widget, soundcloud, autoplay

I'm well aware that Apple has restricted autoplay for audio and video for iOS, and that it requires the player itself to be manually clicked. This is annoying because I'm trying to develop a javascript based Radio type web app which needs to automatically jump after playing one track to the next.

I was doing this in my web app by simply loading the next track in the SC Widget which was set to autoplay. Of course, this works fine on desktop, but is disabled on iOS.

I've noticed however, that playlists within the SC Widget have the ability to automatically jump from one track to the next on iOS, so maybe I can use that instead of my own manual system. So, my idea is to send say 50-100 songs at a time into some sort of temporary generic SC playlist and have the user click Play to get the first one started.

Before I get into the nitty gritty on how to do this, whether or not I can generate a 'generic' playlist without having to setup and account, etc. I just want to verify there isn't another solution available to let songs flow one to the other once the process is manually started.

thanks
-Mike

Comment: There's one important note – the widget is able to do this only *after* first interaction – so the user initiates the first play and then the async. play calls on HTML5 Audio are allowed.

Comment: @gryzzly how are the async play calls done? Will this work if i'm loading a new song into the widget?  Here's a link to my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34330797/how-is-soundcloud-auto-playing-the-next-song-on-their-mobile-site

I have just about everything figured out except for this little bit.  Any tips?